# Type conversion with functions

Tags: powershell

I am hacking in many languages like C/C++, Java, C# and others. Powershell is just a new one to the list. So sometimes I get blind for simple things... I get type conversion errors and can't see why... I try to strongly type ps scripts, but I do something wrong. Here two functions I have written:

```
function Get-DBConnection
{
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection])]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 1)]
    [String]$DBServer,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 2)]
    [int]$DBPort,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 3)]
    [string]$DatabaseName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 4)]
    [string]$UserName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 5)]
    [string]$Password
)

$DBConnectionString = "server=$MyDBServer;port=$MyDBPort;user id=$MyUid;password=$MyPwd;database=$MyDatabase;pooling=false"
$DBConn = New-Object -TypeName Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString
$DBConn.Open

return $DBConn
}

function execute-Query
{
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([System.Data.DataSet])]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection]$DBConnection,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Query
)

$DBCmd = $DBConnection.CreateCommand()
$DBCmd.CommandText = $Query
$adapter = New-Object -TypeName Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter $DBCmd
$dataset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset)

return $dataset
}
```

Now in my script I try to call them as follows:

```
$MyDBConnection = New-Object -TypeName Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection
$MyResultset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table1;"

$MyDBConnection = Get-DBConnection "servername" 5432 "dbname" "username" "pass"
```

When stepping through the script with the debugger, the type of the variable *$MyDBConnection* changes to *Object[]* after the call to Get-DBConnection!
I do **NOT** understand what is going on here.

As a (logic) consequence I get a type conversion error when calling

```
$MyResultset = execute-Query $MyDBConnection $query
```

saying that the paramter DBConnection (the name in the function...) cannot be converted from *System.Object[]* to *Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection*.

Any help and explanation what is going wrong here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$DBConn.Open` -> `$DBConn.Open()`

Comment: Nope, it returns: exception when calling open with 0 arguments. The help does not show me arguments. This method is from a .NET postgres data provider driver....

Comment: Then you have to read that exception message, understand it and eliminate the cause of the exception. But you have to call `Open` method anyway, without that connection is unusable.

Comment: Ok, you helped me! There was another problem (shame on me, copy paste!) The connection string contained the wrong parameter names! So all fields where empty....  And YES, Open() is then correct. Works now, THANK YOU!

Comment: BTW, the OutputType attribute is more of a "type hint" AFAIK.  I don't believe it is actually enforced?

Comment: I currently use a test version of Sapien PowerShell Studio 2015. It has  wizards for functions, modules etc. The code skeleton was generated by the wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PowerShell you don't have to "return" anything explicitly.  Anything that emits to the pipeline is "returned".  Most likely you have two different calls each emitting to the pipeline, which PowerShell automatically converts to an array of objects.   My guess is that $DBConn.Open emits a pipeline object, then you are also "returning" the $DBConn.

A side note, in the last line, just don't use the return statement.  By simply typing a variable by itself on a line, it will be emitted to the pipeline.

Also the crux of your confusion is that PowerShell uses the pipeline, not returning in other languages like C, C++ or C#.   Study the pipeline cause this is the proper way to write functions for PowerShell

Comment: Interesting. Return seems to be optional. See `Get-Help about_Return`. The cause was a different one (see comment above). But one question: I am used to distinguish properties from methods by adding parantheses to the name. So object.open() is a method, object.open a property. This is true in PS as well right?

Comment: Yes in general this is true.  Although remember at that level you are interacting with .NET objects, so whatever holds true for them is generally reflected in Powershell as well.  Properties can call underlying accessor methods, so you might be invoking a method exposed by a get() or set(), instead of a naked property, similar to C#